# How to detect if a folder has been added to the vscode workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Can any vscode extension detect if a folder has been added to the workspace?

That would be the file, add folder to workspace menu option.

Once the folder is added to the workspace, I want to use `FileSystemWatcher` to watch for changes in the folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `vscode.workspace.onDidChangeWorkspaceFolders` event. It is fired with a [WorkspaceFoldersChangeEvent](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceFoldersChangeEvent) with has the added and removed folders